# How to refresh data with layout inflater?

Tags: android, android-layout

What I'm going to do is inflate a cardview in my linear layout.

There's nothing in view when the activity created, but when I enter a url in edittext, the cardview appears.

But when I re-enter other url in edittext, the cardview does not change.

I want to know how to refresh the cardview or the linear layout which is parent view of my cardview.

Here's my code.

First, onPostExecute method of my htmlPareseTask

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> strings) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        View linkView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_link, parentLayout);

        TextView ogTitle = (TextView) linkView.findViewById(R.id.title_link);
        TextView ogDecription = (TextView) linkView.findViewById(R.id.description_link);
        TextView ogUrl = (TextView) linkView.findViewById(R.id.url_link);
        ImageView ogImage = (ImageView) linkView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_link);

        ogTitle.setText(strings.get(0));
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(strings.get(1)).into(ogImage);
        ogDecription.setText(strings.get(2));
        ogUrl.setText(strings.get(3));

        linkView.invalidate();



        super.onPostExecute(strings);
```

Tulsi's Answer reflected :

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> strings) {
        if(linkView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            linkView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_link, view);
            ogTitle = (TextView) linkView.findViewById(R.id.title_link);
            ogDecription = (TextView) linkView.findViewById(R.id.description_link);
            ogUrl = (TextView) linkView.findViewById(R. id.url_link);
            ogImage = (ImageView) linkView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_link);
        }

        ogTitle.setText(strings.get(0));
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(strings.get(1)).into(ogImage);
        ogDecription.setText(strings.get(2));
        ogUrl.setText(strings.get(3));
```

Tulsi's answer reflected 2nd

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> strings) {
        if(linkView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            linkView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_link, null);
            view.addView(linkView);
            ogTitle = (TextView) linkView.findViewById(R.id.title_link);
            ogDecription = (TextView) linkView.findViewById(R.id.description_link);
            ogUrl = (TextView) linkView.findViewById(R. id.url_link);
            ogImage = (ImageView) linkView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_link);
        }else
            {
                view.removeAllViews();
                view.addView(linkView);
            }

        ogTitle.setText(strings.get(0));
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(strings.get(1)).into(ogImage);
        ogDecription.setText(strings.get(2));
        ogUrl.setText(strings.get(3));


        super.onPostExecute(strings);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you re enter text in editText it goes onPostExecute(List strings) and inflate a new CardView in recyclerView. So might me new inserted view is not visible as it is hidden by previous Cardview.
It can be resolved in two way

1. Suppose of `linearLayout` is `instance` of `LinearLayout` in which
   you inflating the cardView. Just call remove method to clear the
   linearlayout `linearLayout.removeAllViews`.
2. Make view as a global variable check if it is `Null` then only inflate the new view otherwise only modify the content.

use this

```
if(linkView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            linkView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_link, null);
            ogTitle = (TextView) linkView.findViewById(R.id.title_link);
            ogDecription = (TextView) linkView.findViewById(R.id.description_link);
            ogUrl = (TextView) linkView.findViewById(R. id.url_link);
            ogImage = (ImageView) linkView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_link);
            view.addView(linkView);
        }
        ogTitle.setText(strings.get(0));
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(strings.get(1)).into(ogImage);
        ogDecription.setText(strings.get(2));
        ogUrl.setText(strings.get(3));
        super.onPostExecute(strings);}
```

Comment: I've tried first one already, but it didn't work. So I tried the second one but still don't work. Please check my edited question!

Comment: view is parent layout instance of linear layout.

Comment: where you are calling view.addView(linkView)?

Comment: By this code, linkView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_link, view), view is already parent of linkView.

Comment: linkView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_link, null); view.addView(linkView); I can write this as well. I'm not sure which one is better.

Comment: use this linkView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_link, null) only when linkView is null!

Comment: check my edited question. The linkView always return same view which means the view never change. I guess we should initialize the instance of linkView.

Comment: The second view.addView(linkView); will raise error because you already attached linkView to view. and when I remove the second view.addView(linkView), it still don't work. I cannot refresh my view.

Comment: Sorry Tulsi, I finally got the answer. Our code was right, but my return values of strings were wrong. I'm sorry for wasting your time :(

Comment: Great to hear that you got the solution!